# How to install numba library on Jetson tx2?

Tags: python, nvidia, numba, nvidia-jetson

I want to install numba on my jetson tx2 so that I can use tf-pose-estimation. All my libraries are not on the anaconda python3 but on the base python instead so I would like to download the numba library without using anaconda. Can you walk me through how to install the numba library on the jetson (etc. what additional packages I have to install before install the numba library)

I have tried pip3 install numba but the install fails when building llvmlite. My python version is 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Juliet Teoh. You need to install LLVM 7.0.1 first and then Numba. For LLVM, you need to run this:

```
$ wget http://releases.llvm.org/7.0.1/llvm-7.0.1.src.tar.xz
$ tar -xvf llvm-7.0.1.src.tar.xz
$ cd llvm-7.0.1.src.tar.xz
$ mkdir llvm_build_dir
$ cd llvm_build_dir/
$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="ARM;X86;AArch64"
$ make -j4
$ sudo make install
$ cd bin/
$ echo "export LLVM_CONFIG=\""`pwd`"/llvm-config\"" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "alias llvm='"`pwd`"/llvm-lit'" >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ sudo pip3 install llvmlite
```

For Numba, you can run this:

```
$ sudo pip3 install numba
```

I put this instruction in https://github.com/jefflgaol/Install-Packages-Jetson-ARM-Family. You may find another installation tutorial there too.

Answer (score 0):

Install [conda4aarch64](https://github.com/jjhelmus/conda4aarch64/releases). This will create a minimal conda environment.

Add the `c4aarch64` and `conda-forge` channels to your conda configuration:

`conda config --add channels c4aarch64`

`conda config --add channels conda-forge`

Then you can install Numba from the `numba` channel:

`conda install -c numba numba`